# Using F# Custom Operator Caused FS0002 Compile Error

Tags: f#

I defined some custom pipeline operators for `Async` and `Task` objects, but get compile error FS0002.

```fs
[<AutoOpen>]
module AsyncOperators =
    type AsyncOperatorHelper = AsyncOperatorHelper with
        static member (=>) (computation, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            fun cont ->
                async.Bind(computation, cont)

        static member (=>) (computation: Task<'a>, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            fun cont ->
                async.Bind(computation |> Async.AwaitTask, cont)

        static member (=>) (computation: Task, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            fun cont ->
                async.Bind(computation |> Async.AwaitTask, cont)

        static member (=->) (cont: 'a -> Task<'b>, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            cont >> Async.AwaitTask

        static member (=->) (cont: 'a -> Task, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            cont >> Async.AwaitTask

        static member (=->) (cont: 'a -> Async<'t>, AsyncOperatorHelper) =
            cont

    let inline (|~>) a b = (a => AsyncOperatorHelper) (b =-> AsyncOperatorHelper)
    let inline (>~>) a b x = x |> (a =-> AsyncOperatorHelper) |~> (b =-> AsyncOperatorHelper)

    let _test () =
        let x = async.Return 0
        let add1 = fun (s: int) -> (async.Return(s + 1))

        // COMPILE OK !!
        let y = x |~> add1

        // But if I expand add1 in the expression: 
        // error FS0002: This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected
        let z = x |~> (fun (s: int) -> (async.Return(s + 1)))
        ()
```

The two expressions look the same, but why the second one get FS0002 error? How can I fix the problem?